# Rigorous hypothesis for Reynolds' transport theorem

Tags: analysis

I'm looking for rigorous hypothesis for the application of Reynolds' transport theorem :

$$
  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left[
    \int_{\Omega(t)}
      \phi({\bf x},t)
    \mathrm{d}{\bf x}
  \right] =
  \int_{\Omega(t)} 
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\phi({\bf x},t)
  \mathrm{d}{\bf x} +
  \int_{\partial\Omega(t)}
    \phi({\bf x},t)\frac{\mathrm{d} {\bf x}}{\mathrm{d} t}.{\bf n}_b
  \mathrm{d}{\bf x},
$$
where $\Omega(t)$ is a piecewice smooth manifold with boundaries (a portion of a polyhedron for instance), $\partial\Omega(t)$ is the boundary of $\Omega(t)$ and ${\bf n}_b$ is the normal of $\partial\Omega(t)$ at ${\bf x}$. In particular, provided all the integrals are well defined of course, I'm interested in the case when $\phi$ is only piecewise smooth, and when the parameterizations I can find of the boundary $\partial\Omega(t)$ are only piecewise continuously differentiable.

Thanks for any help.